# Why was Hasheem Thabeet reinstated after being ejected?

Tags: nba, officiating

In the [November 28 2012](http://sports.yahoo.com/news/thunder-beat-rockets-120-98-032915073--nba.html) game between the OKC Thunder and the Houston Rockets, Thunder forward Hasheem Thabeet was ejected from the game. Shortly thereafter he was reinstated and returned to the court and a technical was assessed.

What was the ruling that allowed him to return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officials have elastic power. In this case, Thabeet pushed official Marc Davis, who came up from behind, before realizing he was an official<sub>([1](http://probasketballtalk.nbcsports.com/2012/11/29/hasheem-thabeets-strange-ejection-then-reversal-by-refs/))</sub>. As you mention, although Davis had initially ejected him, he brought Thabeet back after watching a replay of the incident.

---

**Rule 2, Section III - Elastic Power** states, in part:

> The officials shall have the power to make decisions on any point not
>   specifically covered in the rules.